# Finding Equilibrium Points of System with Bifurcation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

The question given is to discuss all bifurcations of the system:

$\dot{x}=x^2+y^2-2$   ,    $\dot{y}=y-x^2+\alpha$

I know how to discuss bifurcations and what to do after finding the point at which the number of equilibrium points change, however I'm having trouble finding the equilibrium points of the system.

Can I get a little bit of help in finding the equilibrium points of this system?

I know that $\dot{x}=0$ only when $x^2+y^2=2$ which would mean $x=\pm1$ and $y=\pm1$ but that doesn't seem to help when subbing into $\dot{y}$.

Comment: $w^2+(1-2\alpha)w-2=0$
From this I am lost. I know I'm missing something, apparently my factorising is rusty.
I am trying to use the two squares method since I feel like the quadratic formula complicates things immensely since I end up with: $w=\frac{-1+2\alpha\pm\sqrt{4\alpha^2-4\alpha+9}}{2}$


But once I've worked out w i then substitute that back into x^2, solve for x, and then sub back into w. Whatever my values of x and y are they become my equilibrium points?

Comment: Ah thanks. This means i end up with 4 solutions for x and 2 for y. Which means I end up with 8 equilibrium points?

Comment: Okay after some more work I seem to have hit a standstill. I can't seem to find the bifurcation of this system.
The number of equilibrium points never seems to change.
My equilibirum points take the form:
$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-1+2\alpha\pm\sqrt{4*\alpha^2-4*\alpha+9}}{2}}$,
$y=x^2-\alpha$
To find out the bifurcation point I checked when both x and y exist. And I found that y will always exist however x only exists when the inside is a plus and has nothing to do with the change in $\alpha$.

Is there really no bifurcation of this system? Or am I doing something wrong? Please help.